# .How to compute scores based on multiple parameters elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two parameters to be based on which the scoring is to be done,
  1. a distance factor ,from the location of the user to the location of the destinations
  2. a rating factor, there are rating for each destination
The distance factor is to be given more weightage if it falls under the required radius(say 5 km). And the rating factor should be multiplied with the distance score and a new score should be computed. How to do this kind of scoring in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Use function_score of elasticsearch.Basically function score is the array of individual boosters for each type of query/decay/script.For distance you can use decay functions, elasticsearch ships with three types of decay Linear, Exponential and Gauss decay with offset, scale and decay parameters.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

For rating booster write a script to return the rating from the doc_values.
To aggregate the score from individual boosters inside the function query, use score_mode and boost_mode.

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {

            "functions": [{
                    "linear": {
                        "FIELD": {
                            "origin": "",
                            "scale": "",
                            "offset": ""
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "script_score": {
                        "script": "doc['ratinf_field'].value"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boost_mode": "max",
            "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
```

Hope this works for you.